# changing an uncontrolled input of type file in React

Tags: reactjs, redux-form

i  created redux-form to upload form-data with file. but i stumped in how handle the file input, when i tried to select file from form browser console it throw this error

> component is changing an uncontrolled input of type file to be controlled. Input elements should not switch from uncontrolled to controlled.......

**fileupload.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Field, reduxForm } from "redux-form";
import Card from "@material-ui/core/Card";

class RegisterShop extends Component {
  state = {};

  renderField(field) {
    return (
      <div>
        <label>{field.label}</label>
        <input className="form-control" type={field.type} {...field.input} />
      </div>
    );
  }
  onSubmit(values) {
  let formData = new FormData();
    ////
  }

  render() {
    const { handleSubmit } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        <Card>
          <h1>Register Shop</h1>
          <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.onSubmit.bind(this))}>
            <Field
              label="Shop Name"
              name="shopname"
              type="text"
              component={this.renderField}
            />
            <Field
              label="Describe about your shop"
              name="description"
              type="text"
              component={this.renderField}
            />
            <Field
              label="Email"
              name="email"
              type="text"
              component={this.renderField}
            />
            <Field
              label="Contact No"
              name="mobileno"
              type="text"
              component={this.renderField}
            />
            <Field
              label="Location"
              name="locatiion"
              type="text"
              component={this.renderField}
            />
            <Field
              label="Shop Logo"
              name="image"
              type="file"
              component="----------"  //I changed this many ways still get same error
            />
            <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">
              Login
            </button>
          </form>
          <br />
          <br />
        </Card>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default reduxForm({
  form: "registershop"
})(RegisterShop);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is here.

```
<input className="form-control" type={field.type} {...field.input} />
```

First time, field.input is undefined, so fields is blank object , and input field will like this, which is "an uncontrolled input".

```
<input>undefined</input>
```

And after type something in field, the field.input will have value,so be controlled component.
And maybe change to this:

```
  <Field
          label="Shop Logo"
          name="image"
          type="file"
          component={MyFile}
          dataAllowedFileExtensions="jpg png bmp"></Field>
 />
```

MyFile component:

```
class MyFile extends Component {
  render() {
    const { input,dataAllowedFileExtensions } = this.props
    const onInputChange = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const files = [...e.target.files];
        input.onChange(files);
    };
    return (
      <div>
        <input type="file"
               onChange={onInputChange}
               data-allowed-file-extensions={dataAllowedFileExtensions}               />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: text field are working fine problem is when i select the file to upload

Comment: @DulangaHeshan sorry about the misunderstandings,I have changed my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Because it’s uncontrolled component,  you probably want to leave it as:

```
<input type=“file”>
```

Then figure out how to process the input. 
From:
[React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html)

> In React, an input type="file" is always an uncontrolled component because its value can only be set by a user, and not programmatically.
>   You should use the File API to interact with the files. The following example shows how to create a ref to the DOM node to access file(s) in a submit handler:

```
<input type="file" ref={this.fileInput} />
```

Comment: Post the complete React code including function calls and render method-I can’t see what you changed

Comment: sry i'm not understand dou you want to see reduxForm file